# Svn merge problems

Tags: svn, merge

i have a next repository

```
/
 /branches
 /tags
 /trunk - unfortunately all source code for one project goes here
```

now i need start a new project, but i don't want to create it in the trunk because it leads to mixing two projects.

i want to create a new folder in the root of the repository

```
/newp - for example
```

But i need one subproject from the old project that is here: /trunk/folder/folder1
folder1 contains a lot of files

i want to create a folder /newp/folder1 and merge /trunk/folder/folder1 to /newp/folder1, when i do it, only subfolders of /trunk/folder/folder1 are merged to /newp/folder1. files are ignored. Why? I need ability to merge data in both ways. What is the best way to accomplish it?

Pls, tell me if the task is not intelligible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the term "merge" means only one thing in SVN, and I think "merge" is not what you actually want. I do not know why only folders are created in /newp/folder1, and files are not. It could be that you selected the wrong option when doing the action, but I also don't know what action you have done, because you haven't mentioned that.

What you should do is make an [external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) definition. In `/newp` create an external with folder name `folder1` that points to `/trunk/folder/folder1`. That's it. Make sure that `folder1` does not exist before making an external.

Since the external is in the same repository as the working copy you will have a single commit operation (very convenient). If it were the case that external is in another repository then you would have to commit the working copy and the external in two separate operations.

I would also recommend that you move branches/tags/trunk folders to some folder called `oldp` so that you have a better project hierarchy.

Comment: thx for the response. maybe you're right and external is the best way. i'll read more about this function. i hoped that merge operation could help me. it is strange that only folders are copied during merge. i started using svn recently, so i use svn tortoise. this is the reason why there are not any commands, but i tried all kinds of merging that was suggested

Comment: One question, can I change the source code of externals and than commit it?

Comment: > oldp advice - I would, but i don't have premissions for that :)

Comment: @EugenePetrov Is the actual question "what happens when some file is changed in /newp/folder1 and the change commited"? The answer is the change will be actually committed to the file in /trunk/folder/folder1. External only "points" to that folder. If you don't want that, but to keep separate sources of folder1 then you have to "branch" the folder. When folders are branched any change in one has to be manually "merged" to another (and this is where "merge" occurs).

Comment: @EugenePetrov one valid alternative to oldp/newp problem is to create brand new repository. So, current repository is for instance "oldp". New SVN repository is "newp" with the same starting structure, branches/tags/trunk. In repository "oldp" someone has to branch current `folder1` into `branches` folder, and you make an external to that branch in `trunk` of "newp" repository. Commits are separated, but that is not a terrible inconvenience.

Comment: I'm not a person who is responsible for the server with repositories. I just need to create a new project with described dependencies. And i can create it only where i was said to create it :) but your answers are really helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you need is to add assemble that your need from that project as third-party.
Or create branch and add a folder for your project.
It's not bad if trunk contains several projects and features being developed.

You cannot branch part of trunk, only everything.
And that is good because before merge to trunk you should have successful build of all sources, not only part of them.
Don't share projects between trunks it will be difficult to work with them in future.

Comment: thx, for response, but it's not true that you cant to create a branch from a sub directory. you can do it from any directory. it is ok if trunk contains a lot of projects, but if it looks /trunk/project1, /trunk/project2, in my case, trunk is the root of all source code of the project1 and it is a little mess to put the second project there. it is like /trunk/project1/project2. I need only one folder from project1, that is why i need a copy of it. i don't want to have all projects at once in my workcopy. i need only /project2, there is a folder-copy (/project2/folderFromProject1)